# How can I find matching JsonPaths of JSON elements?

Tags: python, json, jsonpath

Ok imagine we have a BIG json objects with an unknown structure.

For example, we want to extract user IDs from a very big data dump, with many subkeys.

We only know that the field names are `user_id` but we don't know the exact path. It may be something like `$.db.users[*].user_id` or `$.account[*].user_id` or anything else.

And lets assume we don't want to extract users that have been banned - so nothing like `$.profiles.banned.user_id` should be searched.

So I'd like to:

1. Run something and *map* our big JSON object, having ALL possible paths containing specified field name (`user_id`) in our case.
2. Choose then what path(s) I want to use to extract the fields.
3. Extract the data (I can do then it using any JsonPath library, so no difficulties here).

The goal - again - is to understand the structure of the document, to list all possible JsonPath-compatible paths (step 1).

Then I can choose what JsonPath(s) I want to use and actually extract the data.

Is there any way to do it? Preferable, in Python (but not obligatory).

Comment: Probably recursion, you'd want to walk the entire dictionary, while checking if the current key is the key your looking for.